# Im making a bat file ment to be opened with another file how would i get the file?

Tags: batch-file

I am going to make a code that I open with another file through the operating system i will do so by right clicking it and clicking open with then selecting my code this code will be a bat file and i need to get the path of the file it was opened with so is there a way i could do this and if so how would I? I'm compiling my go code files with this so the code should look something like this

```
set file = (Gets the file and path here)
go run file
```

is this even possible? and if i need to do this in another language what would that be

Comment: Yes, it's possible, Even if it is a very impractable method of going about opening a file.  Please understand this site is for questions regarding specific issues with code that is not working as expected, Not for broad questions of the `can I / If so, how can I?` type such as yours that show no effort in researching or attempting to solve the problem. [Please take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before asking further questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fortunately enough found my answer so this is the code to run.

```
@echo off
echo %1
cmd /k
```